# Silverlight MVVM question regarding views and viewmodels

Tags: silverlight, mvvm, mvvm-light

I feel mysefl confused about how to implement view switching when view model changes. 
Example of what i'm tring to do:

The control I want to make is something like a wizard control. I have a list of view models added to collection of wizardsteps, and a current item viewmodel. How to display the view of active view model and switch them then active view model changes? How do I bind them?

 In WPF I'd use DataTemplate but Silverlight doesn't support x:Type.

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModel1}">
  <view:View1 />
</DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModel2}">
  <view:View2 />
</DataTemplate>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think a wizard is a case where you should have one ViewModel for multiple Views.

You could control the visibility of each view with Properties (IsPage1Visible, IsPage2Visible,...), Commands (PreviowsPageCommand, NextPageCommand, CancelComamnd) and all logic in only one VM.

Put all "pages" of the wizard in one UserControl and bind the visilitiy of each with the boolean properties and a BooleanToVisibilityConverter.

Answer (score 1):

Check this out, it talks about non-linear navigation in SL/WPF and how to maintain state.  http://karlshifflett.wordpress.com/2010/07/07/non-linear-navigation-in-silverlight-4/